# RHEL 6: GNOME: staring a *.desktop file in a shell different from the system default

Tags: bash, desktop, rhel-6, csh

I'm in RHEL 6 with bash as my default shell.

I have a script called startServers

I made a startServers.desktop file which I put on my desktop so I can have the convenience of clicking on an icon to start the script.

It works fine.

Some friends want to use my script.  They too are on RHEL 6, but their default shell is CSH.

When I click on "properties" for startServers.desktop I have a text field called "Commands" that is just

/pathtofile/startServers

Can I alter that field so that double clicking on the icon sends the command to bash instead of CSH ?  Something like

bash /pathtofile/startServers ?

Thanks

Comment: If you set a hashbang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) in the first line, this shouldn't be required?

Comment: I gave it a shot.  It made no difference, but thanks for responding.

Comment: maybe `#!/bin/sh`. Remember to put it in the very first line

Comment: The script is written in bash so I don't think #/bin/sh would help.