# RHEL 6 converting a BASH script to a CSH script

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, rhel-6, csh

I have a BASH script( running on RHEL 6 ) that brings up a GNOME terminal, opens multiple tabs in that terminal, starts a server in each tab, names the tab after that server, and inserts the command into the BASH history.  Here is a simplified version of it:

```
gnome-terminal   \
--tab -t "Server One"  -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"$LONGPATH/bin/startServerOne.sh \"; exec bash"'

echo $LONGPATH/bin/startServerOne.sh >>~/.bash_history;
```

I made this script a while ago and I embarrassed to say I don't remember 100% of why I did what I did.  I'm not familiar with CSH.

Basically, I am wondering what I have to do in the code sample above to convert those BASH commands into CSH commands

Thanks for any info

Comment: [See my comment on your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/934629/rhel-6-gnome-staring-a-desktop-file-in-a-shell-different-from-the-system-def#comment1268232_934629).